# Decision Problems and Poly Time

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

We have Two Decision Problem A and B. we know A is NP-Complete, but B can be solved in $O(n^2lg^4n)$, and we know $B \leq_pA $ (i.e each problem of B can be convert to a problem of A in Polynomial Time). Which of them is inferred from the above axioms.

1- P= NP and each NP problem can be solved in $O(n^3)$

2- P=NP and some NP Problems need times more than $O(n^3)$ to solve.

3-$ P \neq NP$

40 none of them.

this is a question on Entrance Exam on Computer Science on 2013. one of my friends says second is true and the first is false.

EDIT: I mentioned the whole question.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the question? The problem seems like homework, and for such problems we look for the person asking the question to show some effort, not merely copy a problem onto this site.

Comment: Also, do you really mean $B \leq_p A$?

Comment: Dear @CarlMummert, no it's a short solved ex. yes.

Comment: Neither (1) nor (2) is true - the assumptions do not cause $P = NP$.  But, until you explain what you have tried, there is no way for anyone to help clarify where you went wrong.

Comment: Dear @CarlMummert, I'm sorry, I clarify whole question. I need some description about the correct one. I think the (2) is true. would you please clarify me? thanks again.

Comment: Dear Professor @CarlMummert, would you please your idea about this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B\le A$, there is no good answer, because it's an open question to know if $P=NP$, so we don't know if one of them or none of them can be inferred from the hypotheses. Note that $B\le A$ is suspicious because it can be inferred from the fact that $A$ is $NP$-complete, so it is not really an hypothesis.

if $A\le B$, it means that we can solve $A$ in polynomial time. As $A$ is $NP$-complete, it means that $NP\subseteq P$ so $P=NP$. However it is easy, by diagonalization, to create problems in $P$ that can be solved in more than $O(n^3)$. So the second answer is good in this case.

Comment: Dear @Xoff, would you please say, in this case the (2) is the answer? am I right ?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh Only if $A\le B$ and not if $B\le A$ only.

Comment: you means in this question without modification (4) is the best answer?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh I mean there is no good answer. The (4) would imply that we know there is no proof that can be inferred from the hypotheses. But today, we don't know any proof and we don't know if there is a proof. (4) would be a good answer if we know there is no proof and we could safely say none of the first three answers can be inferred from the hypotheses. But even that we don't know.

Comment: I thin the question say, there is a problem like B that can be reduction to a NP-Complete problem. in reduction either the complexity class is saved or reduced and so the NP-Complete problem found a polynomial solution. and so each NP can be reduced polynomial to NP-Complete, finally each problem of NP found a Polynomial solution, then P=NP.

Comment: @MaryamGhizh No, if problem $B$ can be reduced to problem $A$, then either the complexity class of $A$ is the same as $B$ or it is more complex.

Comment: I confused exactly :) so you means in the above question none of them is  not good choice ! thanks anyway.

Comment: you say,  by diagonalization, to create problems in P  that can be solved in more than ...., But that can't be inferred from the given statements? am I right?

Comment: @MaryamGhizh to be able to use the given statements, you need more things : for example you need to have the definition of NP, and NP-complete. From those definitions, you can inferred by diagonalisation that something lies outside $0(n^3)$. So it's not directly from those given statements, but it's from the minimal mathematical frame needed to understand those statements.